# Wine .exe needs access to shared folder on network

Tags: networking, wine

I previously used a Ubuntu computer for DATA which was accessed/edited by a LAN full of Win7 computers - no problem.  Now I'm considering replacing Win7 computers with Bionic Beaver run computers.  I can get the individual linux computers to run a Wine .exe and access local data, but I've been unable to get the Wine .exe to access DATA on a shared linux computer.  The DATA computer folder is available via Files/Other_Locations, but I can't figure out how to access it via the Wine .exe.  Is there a mapping, mounting, or some other technique that I need to learn?

Comment: ALSO - I can still access the DATA on the linux computer from Win7 computers, running the .exe built with the Visual Foxpro programming language.

Comment: Can I mount the shared directory in each local computer's */.wine/drive_c and access it by initializing my .exe to find c\shared_directory?

Comment: What Windows client app are you running in WINE which needs access?

Comment: I'm running a standalone .exe built from Visual Foxpro.  It runs just fine in WINE for local data access, but I need to access data files on a shared network computer (also running linux ubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Ubuntu file server, then on your Ubuntu workstations, mount the path to the shared data, a lá:

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=Administrator,password=yourPasswordHere //server/folder /mnt/windows
```

An interesting explanation may be found if you open https://www.viamais.net/blog/estendendo-suporte-a-unc-no-wine/ and then have it translate to English.

Comment: Unable to make your suggestion work.  I know it's because I'm not really sure what I'm doing.  My Windows .exe either looks for C:\VFP for local data or \\MAIN\VFP for data on the network shared drive on MAIN.  Wine recognizes the C:\VFP drive because I created the local directory VFP in /home/<user>/.wine/drive_c.  I have no idea what to initialize for WINE to recognize my shared linux directory.  Windows7 recognizes the shared linux directory as \\MAIN\VFP without any problem. I've been unable to figure out where to mount it and how to access it from linux. Sorry for being such a newbie.